# Show additional category on the x-axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, categories

Hiii!

I'm writing my master thesis and I am struggling with the plots.
I want to represent the juvenile fish abundances for each sampled site.
This is what it looks like right now:

```
# Pepraration steps
setwd("~/Desktop/TFM/Datos")
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)

# Import data
mydata <- read.csv("~/Desktop/TFM/Datos/Alevins_2020_SUBSET.csv")

# Colours
col_Dsar <- "aquamarine"

col_NFRA <- "brown"
col_SFRA <- "chocolate1"
col_NESP <- "brown1"
col_SESP <- "darkgoldenrod1"

# Display data
mydata
  Order_NS            Site  Zone Dsar_ST
1         1         Leucate N_FRA   33.40
2         2      Barcarès 3 N_FRA   57.50
3         3      Barcarès 2 N_FRA   24.38
4         4      Barcarès 1 N_FRA   50.00
5         5           Canet N_FRA   12.33
6         6        Portells S_FRA   36.00
7         7   Roches Bleues S_FRA   38.29
8         8    Port-Vendres S_FRA   11.82
9         9     Banyuls_PN1 S_FRA    2.11
10       10     Banyuls_PN2 S_FRA    4.31
11       11     Banyuls_PN3 S_FRA    0.25
12       12     Banyuls_PN4 S_FRA   11.04
13       13     Banyuls_PN5 S_FRA    1.38
14       14     Banyuls_ZP1 S_FRA    1.75
15       15     Banyuls_ZP2 S_FRA    6.59
16       16     Banyuls_ZPR S_FRA    7.35
17       17     Banyuls_ZP3 S_FRA    4.75
18       18     Banyuls_ZP4 S_FRA    6.75
19       19     Banyuls_PN6 S_FRA    1.92
20       20     Banyuls_PN7 S_FRA    4.08
21       21  Port-Bou Rocks S_FRA   23.33
22       22  Port-Bou Beach S_FRA   11.06
23       23          Garbet N_ESP   19.38
24       24           Selva N_ESP   19.14
25       25         Portixó N_ESP    4.71
26       26         Portaló N_ESP    9.71
27       27           Culip N_ESP    4.72
28       28 Racó ses Ielles N_ESP    0.75
29       29       Cala Bona N_ESP    1.50
30       30      Guillola 2 N_ESP    1.67
31       31      Guillola 1 N_ESP    0.00
32       32      Portlligat N_ESP    3.22
33       33          Caials N_ESP   12.76
34       34         Joncols N_ESP   15.56
35       35         Montjoi N_ESP   20.33
36       36           Roses N_ESP   21.11
37       37  Empuriabrava 2 N_ESP   18.86
38       38  Empuriabrava 1 N_ESP   44.41
39       39    Baix de Cols S_ESP    2.63
40       40         Ferriol S_ESP    4.75
41       41         Pedrosa S_ESP    3.25
42       42        Falaguer S_ESP    4.50

# Plot
myplot <- ggplot(data = alevines, mapping = aes(x = reorder(Site, Order_NS), y = mydata$Dsar_ST)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE,
           fill = col_Dsar, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mydata$Dsar_ST),
             linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Settlers density \n (individuals / 100 m of transect)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjus = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60), expand = c(0, 0))
myplot
```

What I now want to do, is to divide the labels of the x-axis into four categories, that are another variable in my data frame (called Zone).

What I was thinking, is something like adding a rectangle that includes the labels of the sites for each zone, and moving the x-axis label a bit lower so that I have space to do this. Then also add the text (zone name), using the same colours. And I would like to use different colours for the zones, the colours that I defined previously.
Sadly I can not add a picture to better explain the problem.

How can I solve this?

Hope I gave enough information, but is the first time that I post here.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi vandalaiza. Are you able to share your data, or a sample of it?

Comment: I can show the heading, is it enough? I just edited the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is simply to plot the bars with a fill corresponding to the Zone:

```
library(tidyverse)

alevines <- tribble(~Order_NS, ~Site, ~Zone, ~Transect..m., ~Dsar_TOT, ~Dsar_ST,
 1, "Leucate", "N_FRA", 500, 167, 33.40,
 2, "Barcarès 3", "N_FRA", 160, 92, 57.50,
 3, "Barcarès 2", "N_FRA", 160, 39, 24.38,
 4, "Barcarès 1", "N_FRA", 160, 80, 50.00,
 5, "Canet", "N_FRA", 430, 53, 12.33,
 6, "Portells", "S_FRA", 400, 144, 36.00)

col_Dsar <- "aquamarine"

pDsar <- ggplot(data = alevines, mapping = aes(x = reorder(Site, Order_NS), 
                                               y = Dsar_ST,
                                               fill = Zone)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(alevines$Dsar_ST),
             linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Settlers density \n (individuals / 100 m of transect)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 16, hjus = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16)) +
  ylim(0, 60)

pDsar
```

[image: Barplot with colored bars]

If you want to add colored boxes under the axis, you can do this with an additional geom (don't forget to change the ylim so that it's displayed:

```
ggplot(data = alevines, mapping = aes(x = reorder(Site, Order_NS), y = Dsar_ST, fill = "red")) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE,
           fill = col_Dsar, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(alevines$Dsar_ST),
             linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  geom_tile(aes(y=-1, fill=Zone),height=2) +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Settlers density \n (individuals / 100 m of transect)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 16, hjus = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16)) +
  ylim(-2, 60)
```

[image: Boxes under the x axis]

Finally, you might get something better with `annotation_custom()` and playing with `grid` but I couldn't find how to do it easily.

Comment: Hey Alexlok, first of all, thank you for your time! I can not change the bar fills, I need them to be that colour because I have more species to plot. The second option is working a bit better, but I do not like that I get a Legend. Is there any way I can put the legend text on the tile itself? And how can I change the colours that R is assigning to the tiles?

Comment: You can add `show.legend = FALSE` to the `geom_tile()` as you did with the `geom_col()`. To change the color scale, use `scale_fill_*()` with * manual, brewer, or something that you like. To add text, you can use `geom_text()`, e.g. `geom_text(aes(y=-2, color=Zone, label=Zone), show.legend = FALSE)` (and in that case you control the color with `scale_color_*()`).

Comment: Cool! I am almost there, but two more things remain: (1) I don't seem able to control which Zone takes which colour. I tried with ````limits = alevines$Zone````but I get an error saying that I need 42 colours (that is the number of site) but I am only specifying 4. (2) I am trying this for the text: ````geom_text(aes(y = -1.5, colour = "black", label = Zone), show.legend = FALSE)```` but first it is not black (I said I wanted it the same colour as for zone but I changed my mind :D) and it appears 42 times, one for each site. I would like to have it in the middle of the tile, in black.

Comment: For the color, take `colour="black"` out of the `aes()`: it is not a mapping. To have it only once in the middle of the group of bars, I don't see how to do that simply with `geom_text()`, you can define it "manually" with `annotation_*()` (to draw the rectangles and the text only where you specify it, and not how the data specifies it which would be once for every `Site`).

Comment: aaah right, I feel stupid now. Ok I managed to change it to black, but I will try with annotation_*(), although it seems quite a difficult function to me. Otherwise I will just add it later, at the end is only four text boxes and does not worth it to go crazy for it. No ideas on how to solve the question (1) in my previous comment?

Comment: `scale_fill_manual()`, but make sure the `fill="red"` is not in an `aes()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're talking about: You're looking for something like the multiple rows in x axes that Excel PivotCharts give when you split your data multiple ways, right? I don't know of a way to do this in R without a *lot* of hacky workarounds. Instead, have you considered using small multiples to represent your data? Here's an example of small multiples for your data, still using `ggplot2`. I have also removed the extra space between the 0 and the horizontal axis using `expand =`  within the `scale_y_continuous` call.

Data I used:

```
alevines <- data.frame(Order_NS = 1:6, 
                   Site = c("Leucate", "Barcares", "Barcares", "Barcares", 
                            "Canet", "Portells"),
                   Zone = c(rep("N_FRA", 5), "S_FRA"),
                   Transect..m. = c(500, 160, 160, 160, 430, 400),
                   Dsar_TOT = c(167, 92, 39, 80, 53, 144), 
                   Dsar_ST = c(33, 57, 24, 50, 12, 36))
```

Graph:

```
ggplot(alevines, aes(x = reorder(Site, Order_NS), 
                 y = Dsar_ST, fill = "red")) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, 
           fill = col_Dsar, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(alevines$Dsar_ST),
             linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Settlers density \n (individuals / 100 m of transect)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 16, hjus = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Zone, scales = "free")
```

[image]

**One quick note of concern:** Did you mean for the data to be *added* whenever you have multiple observations at the same site, e.g., Barcares? If not, you might try something like this, substituting `ObservationID` for some other unique identifier in your data.

```
alevines$ObservationID <- 1:nrow(alevines)
ggplot(alevines, aes(x = reorder(Site, Order_NS), group = ObservationID,
                 y = Dsar_ST, fill = "red")) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, position = "dodge",
           fill = col_Dsar, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(alevines$Dsar_ST),
             linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Settlers density \n (individuals / 100 m of transect)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 16, hjus = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Zone, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey shirewoman2, I really appreciate you taking time to help me :) I am not an Excel expert either, so what you said is quite confusing, I can not confirm. If only I could put a picture! But I need a better reputation first apparently ahah The first plot nope, I want the 3 Barcares sites as separated. Anyway the second plot it's a nice idea, but I did try with facets already.. problem is, I just one one plot with one y-axis, not one for each zone.. also, I would love to add colours to the text of the axis or whatever, but one colour for each zone.